# How to positioning content inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I try to make a blog article preview and want the header of the article has 0px to the top of the div

```
#Parent {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-color: grey;
}
#Child {
color: white;
position: ?;
top ?;
padding ?;
}
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: it's a game ? we should guess the `?`

Answer (score 0):

To position a child div inside of the parent div, you need to first set the position of the parent div to position: relative. Then you set the child div to position: absolute (and you can then use top/left/right/bottom to place the child div according to its parent). The rule is basically that when you use position: absolute on an element, it will be taken out of the flow of the page and will be placed 'absolutely' according to the closest positioned element.

```
#Parent {
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: grey;
 position: relative; /* new code here */
}
#Child {
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: and if you do nothing the content by default is in the top because it's the default flow behavior :) ... your solution is not relevant because it contains no HTML code, CSS alone means nothing .. .and since the OP doesn't provided his HTML, it's difficult to say what CSS to apply.

Comment: You're right haha :) It's a little hard without any initial html snippet to work with. When I read the question, I interpreted it as the person being a little confused about the css position property (thus the long winded explanation about a css property).